# Mysql optimization for huge data

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, optimization

I am executing following sql statement on a table with 6 million rows:

```
SELECT 
    log.all, max(log.created_date) as latest_date, COUNT(all) AS 
    total_count, type.id as machine_type 
FROM sms_log log, machine mac, 
    machine_type type 
WHERE mac.machine_type_id = type.id 
AND log.machine_id = mac.id 
AND log.from_machine = 1
AND log.phone_number 
    IN(SELECT data FROM machine_data 
       WHERE name = 'phonenumber' 
       AND status = 'active' 
       AND id 
           IN(SELECT machine_data_id 
              FROM machine_connector 
              WHERE connection_type = 'DATA' 
              AND status = 'active' 
              AND machine_id = mac.id)) 
GROUP BY phone_number
ORDER BY total_count DESC LIMIT 100
```

I have indexed few columns, still it does take a lot of time,

help me to optimize the sql!

Comment: I think all good optimization starts with a well-formatted query.

Comment: This query would produce a syntax error. Anyway, you really don't like JOINs, do you?

Comment: "Anyway, you really don't like JOINs, do you?" Some think JOIN's are from the SQL devil not knowing MySQL tends to optimize co-related subqueries even worse. @Strawberry

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: @jarlh or somebody else did outer joins (explicit JOIN syntax) exists in the old days (SQL 86/89)? iám to young to know also because those standards are lost.. i assume you would have to simulate those with co-related subqueries in those days? iám aware off Oracle's `(+)` operator which could convert the old ansi join comma syntax into a outer join.. I think explicit JOIN syntax was from SQL 92 right?

Comment: @RaymondNijland, yes, the explicit JOIN syntax, including OUTER JOIN, was introduced in SQL-92.

Comment: See the section named "Use of Indexes to Satisfy ORDER BY" at [ORDER BY optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html). Also read [EXPLAIN syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html).

Comment: @RaymondNijland: Are you saying that the MySQL documentation is wrong, and that it won't help the OP find problems in his query? I think the OP is doing several things in this query that will hurt performance. The section I cited will point him (and you) to most of them (especially EXPLAIN syntax).

Comment: trust you don't have to redirect me to the explain syntax and or output (for MySQL atleast).. ok i explained it wrong the first time @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' most likely it will not work because off the JOIN's MySQL optimizer would most likely choose the wrong table access order based on the table/index stats so it most likely it would require to a filesort annyway.. Unless MySQL 5.7/8.0 is used which has a better optimizer that knows it needs to acces the order by table first for the other tables.

Comment: Topicstarter i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide example table and expected results.. @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' is right you are doing some things wrong annybody else or i didn't notice you are most likey using the GROUP BY wrong in SQL.Using non aggregate columns in select which are not in the GROUP BY unless all records are functional dependent from the phone_number column which i doubt.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff thanks for your suggestion. This is my first question in stack overflow! will improve

Comment: What about all the other great suggestions?

Comment: You need some composite indexes, but first, let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.